# Apple Photos import: Insufficient Disk Space

Tags: photos.app

I have about 58,000 photos/videos (~1TB) catalog in Lightroom 5.  These photos/videos are stored on an external USB drive.

Since I'm using a very old version of Lightroom, I'm considering moving to Apple Photos (Mojave 10.14.5). I've moved the Photos Library to a folder on the external drive, which has about 530GB of free space.  When I tried to import, Photos complains "Insufficient Disk Space.   Additional 760.47 GB of free space is needed to continue."  In Photos, I've unchecked "Copy items to the Photos Library".   Why does Photos need this much space?  I'd like to keep all the photos exactly where they are.

Comment: Apple's photos.app is in no way a replacement for Lightroom, regardless of what version you have. it is designed for casual, non-professional use. I would venture a guess that throwing that many pictures at photos.app is not going to yield acceptable results. You may need to consider another app.

Comment: You first state that there are 58K photos/videos totaling **~1TB**. Then you state you're trying to move these files to a disk with **530GB** of space. I can see why you're getting an error about not enough disk space. Am I missing something?

Comment: @SteveChambers I found over the years that I don't use very many features of LR, so Photos is likely enough for my basic usage.  I'm OK with losing any changes I've made in LR.

Comment: @IconDaemon I'm not trying to move photos.  My photos are on the external drive.  The "Photos Library.photoslibrary" file is also on the external drive.  As I stated above, I've **unchecked** "Copy items to the Photos Library" so I'm hoping that means that Photos won't make a copy of the existing photos.  If that's true, then why does it need 760GB of space?  Is Photos trying to make another copy of my entire 1GB  collection?

Comment: All I know is that people who try and throw a LOT of pictures at photos.app are not always successful.

Comment: I'd try a very small subset of the photos you are migrating to see what is being created on the disk _and where_. Maybe Photos creates a crapton of thumbnail images as part of its processing. I would recommend you get another external HD and start fresh, but that's just me. It could be an inexpensive solution for you. When you're done, you'll have the originals backed up on one disk, and a new Photos library on another!